# Как сделать запрос на получение наиболее повторяющихся данных (nest/typeorm/postgres)

Tags: postgresql, typescript, поиск, nestjs, typeorm

На сайте есть поиск, необходимо под полем ввода сделать блок "популярные запросы", где будут отображаться наиболее популярные поисковые запросы
Как это правильно реализовать на NestJs / Typeorm / postgres или может для таких целей использовать другую бд?

Comment: *Как это правильно реализовать* Очевидно - фиксировать сделанные запросы и их количество. *или может для таких целей использовать другую бд?* Какая разница-то?

Comment: Любая БД подходит. Как вы храните наиболее популярные запросы?

Comment: пока никак не храню, но планировал в отдельной таблице хранить все поисковые запросы, но не понимаю как найти наиболее популярные среди них